# Keras Multi GPU example gives ResourceExhaustedError

Tags: tensorflow, keras, multi-gpu

So I try to use multiple GPUs with Keras. When I run [training_utils.py](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/training_utils.py) with the example program (given as comments inside the training_utils.py code), I end up with `ResourceExhaustedError`. `nvidia-smi` tells me that barely one of the four GPUs are working. Using one GPU works fine for other programs.

- TensorFlow 1.3.0
- Keras 2.0.8
- Ubuntu 16.04
- CUDA/cuDNN  8.0/6.0

**Question:** Anyone have any idea whats going on here?

*Console output:*

(...)

> 2017-10-26 14:39:02.086838: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:277] ***************************************************************************************************x
>   2017-10-26 14:39:02.086857: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[128,55,55,256]
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "test.py", line 27, in 
>       parallel_model.fit(x, y, epochs=20, batch_size=256)
>     File "/home/kyb/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1631, in fit
>       validation_steps=validation_steps)
>     File "/home/kyb/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1213, in _fit_loop
>       outs = f(ins_batch)
>     File "/home/kyb/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2331, in **call**
>       **self.session_kwargs)
>     File "/home/kyb/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)
>     File "/home/kyb/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1124, in _run
>       feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
>     File "/home/kyb/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
>       options, run_metadata)
>     File "/home/kyb/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1340, in _do_call
>       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
>   tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[128,55,55,256]
>        [[Node: replica_1/xception/block3_sepconv2/separable_conv2d = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:1"](replica_1/xception/block3_sepconv2/separable_conv2d/depthwise, block3_sepconv2/pointwise_kernel/read/_2103)]]
>        [[Node: training/RMSprop/gradients/replica_0/xception/block10_sepconv2/separable_conv2d_grad/Conv2DBackpropFilter/_4511 = _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_25380_training/RMSprop/gradients/replica_0/xception/block10_sepconv2/separable_conv2d_grad/Conv2DBackpropFilter", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]
>
> Caused by op u'replica_1/xception/block3_sepconv2/separable_conv2d',
>   defined at:   File "test.py", line 19, in 
>       parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=2)   File "/home/kyb/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/utils/training_utils.py",
>   line 143, in multi_gpu_model
>       outputs = model(inputs)   File "/home/kyb/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py",
>   line 603, in **call**
>       output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)   File "/home/kyb/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py",
>   line 2061, in call
>       output_tensors, _, _ = self.run_internal_graph(inputs, masks)   File
>   "/home/kyb/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py",
>   line 2212, in run_internal_graph
>       output_tensors = _to_list(layer.call(computed_tensor, **kwargs))   File
>   "/home/kyb/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py",
>   line 1221, in call
>       dilation_rate=self.dilation_rate)   File "/home/kyb/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 3279, in separable_conv2d
>       data_format=tf_data_format)   File "/home/kyb/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py",
>   line 497, in separable_conv2d
>       name=name)   File "/home/kyb/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py",
>   line 397, in conv2d
>       data_format=data_format, name=name)   File "/home/kyb/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py",
>   line 767, in apply_op
>       op_def=op_def)   File "/home/kyb/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 2630, in create_op
>       original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)   File "/home/kyb/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 1204, in **init**
>       self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating
>   tensor with shape[128,55,55,256]   [[Node:
>   replica_1/xception/block3_sepconv2/separable_conv2d =
>   Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1,
>   1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:1"](replica_1/xception/block3_sepconv2/separable_conv2d/depthwise,
>   block3_sepconv2/pointwise_kernel/read/_2103)]]     [[Node:
>   training/RMSprop/gradients/replica_0/xception/block10_sepconv2/separable_conv2d_grad/Conv2DBackpropFilter/_4511
>   = _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1,
>   tensor_name="edge_25380_training/RMSprop/gradients/replica_0/xception/block10_sepconv2/separable_conv2d_grad/Conv2DBackpropFilter",
>   tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

**EDIT (Added example code):**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.applications import Xception
from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model
import numpy as np

num_samples = 1000
height = 224
width = 224
num_classes = 100

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    model = Xception(weights=None,
                     input_shape=(height, width, 3),
                     classes=num_classes)

parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=4)
parallel_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                   optimizer='rmsprop')

x = np.random.random((num_samples, height, width, 3))
y = np.random.random((num_samples, num_classes))

parallel_model.fit(x, y, epochs=20, batch_size=128)
```

Comment: Either your model is too big for your devices, or you're using batches with too many elements.

Comment: You are right, when I'm using a smaller batch size it works. I'm using four GTX 1080 Ti so I didn't think that running the example program would result in a size problem. The example program was meant for 8 GPUs as default. But how much space this program occupy, and how do you calculate it? Is it really more than 11 Gig x 4?

Comment: I don't know how to calculate....I think the best is the good old attempt and fail approach.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyways. Your answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When encountering OOM/ResourceExhaustedError on GPU I believe changing (Reducing) `batch size` is the right option to try at first.

> For different GPU you may need different batch size based on the GPU
>   memory you have.

Recently I faced the similar type of problem, tweaked a lot to do the different type of experiment.

Here is the link to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007984/training-broke-with-resourceexausted-error/48096611#48096611) (also some tricks are included).

However, while reducing the size of the batch you may find that your training gets slower.